# how to get the coordinate of cursor when setting PS1 variable for command line prompt?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ps1

I'm using Mac. I want to set PS1 variable to get current time at the end of line in command line prompt. Like this:
[image: exmaple 1]
or this:
[image: example 2]

But, unfortunately, I can't get what I want through following configuration:

```
CYAN="\[$(tput setaf 6)\]"
GREEN="\[$(tput setaf 2)\]" 
BLUE="\[$(tput setaf 4)\]"
YELLOW="\[$(tput setaf 3)\]" 
export PS1="$GREEN\u$BLUE@$CYAN\h $YELLOW\w\[$(tput cuf $(($(tput cols)-33)))\]$CYAN\[$(date +%H:%M)\]\n\\$ "
```

It seems that I need to get the current position of cursor and do some computations based on the coordinate of the position, but I don't know how to get it. Is anyone can help?

Comment: You might consider using `zsh` instead; it has built-in support for a prompt that appears on the right side of the screen with the `RPROMPT` / `RPS1` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Thomas for the good answer, it can truly solve the question I asked as a work-around solution. But it is not perfect, which means it still cannot get the command prompt that I want.

I found that there should be **no solution for the prompt I want in bash**. But, as @chepner said, there do exist methods to get the prompt in **zsh**.

**How to get the prompt in zsh**:

zsh is a very powerful shell which is built-in in mac, but it's a little complicate for the newbie to it. So there is a great tools to solve it named "[oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)" which make the use of zsh much easier.

"[oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)" include many themes for zsh. And, fortunately, the prompt I want is very similar with one of them([see the themes here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)), which named blink. So I just need to modify a little of the theme file located in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/blinks.zsh-theme` and the change needed to do is:

change the last line of the file from:

`RPROMPT='%{%B%F{cyan}%}%!%{%f%k%b%}`

to

`RPROMPT='%{%B%F{cyan}%}%@%{%f%k%b%}`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues.  This chunk

```
$(tput cuf $(($(tput cols)-33)))
```

appears to be what you are asking about.  If you want to position the date at the end of the line, you might try using the `hpa` (horizontal position absolute) capability, e.g.,

```
$(tput hpa $(($(tput cols)-5)))
```

That way, you can move the cursor to a given *absolute* position on the line rather than moving *relative* to the current position.

The prompt as given occupies two lines.  If you use the `sc` and `rc` capabilities (save/restore cursor) before and after the part where you write the date, you can reduce that to a single line.  That might run into problems with line-editing clearing the date, but it is something to consider.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I found that it's a good solution but not perfect, do you have any ideas to improve it?

Considering following situation:

![screencut](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T4GtY.png)

That is to say, when the path string is long while not long enough to a new line, it will be covered by the date string. Any idea to solve it?

For your recommendation about reducing that to a single line, actually I tried it. But as you said, it has problem with line-editing clearing the date. So I prefer the multiline solution.

Comment: I don't see much possibility for improvement since bash either *knows* the length of a path string itself - and writes it without your formatting - or the string is escaped.

Comment: I found another issue of current solution. When I resize the command line prompt window, the format will be damaged, although I refreshed the prompt. It seems like the setting of PS1 will load just once when the window is launched, so the printed prompt will not change when I resize the window. Any solution?